# Reports in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: reports, arcgis-pro

I just tried to use Reports in ArcGIS Pro 1.2, and have not been able to find them in either the application or its documentation.

A [GeoNet thread](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/115292) asked the same question for ArcGIS Pro 1.1 but that has not been replied to.

Has anyone found them in ArcGIS Pro 1.2, or know when they are expected to be added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reports functionality appears to have been available in ArcGIS Pro 2.3. Here is the documentation for it: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/reports/design-the-report.htm

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is not in ArcGIS Pro at the 1.2 release.  We hope to add it at a future release.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked for this in ArcGIS Pro 1.4 (final) and Reports are not present.

The [ArcGIS Pro Roadmap](https://geonet.esri.com/community/gis/applications/arcgis-pro/blog/2017/03/05/arcgis-pro-roadmap) currently has Reports listed in the Mid-term column.  The Near-term column seems to coincide with what is expected at ArcGIS Pro 2.0 so it looks like this functionality is expected beyond 2.0.

In the meantime the best [workaround for Reports in ArcGIS Pro](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/115292) may be to use ReportLab.